# Can I make my Node app deployed on Heroku available via more domains?

Tags: heroku

I want to have two domains that lead to same Heroku app like following:

```
public.myapp.com
business.myapp.com
```

Can this be set up in Heroku ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can add as many domains as you'd like to your Heroku app by doing the following...

First, tell Heroku what domains you'd like to support:

```
$ heroku domains:add public.myapp.com
$ heroku domains:add business.myapp.com
```

Next, create DNS CNAME records for each of those domains and point it to your Heroku app.

For instance:

```
CNAME public.myapp.com -> my-app.herokuapp.com
CNAME business.myapp.com -> my-app.herokuapp.com
```

That's it!

Once you've got both DNS updated, as well as Heroku configured, it will start accepting incoming requests for whatever domain names you've added =)